Possible problem in textbook derivation of Poisson bracket property for canonical transformation?
The book Classical Mechanics by Alexei Deriglazov defines as canonical a transformation $Z=Z(z,t)$ that preserves the Hamiltonian form of the equation of motion for any $H$. After taking the divergence of the vector equation relating the components of $\dot{Z}$ in the two coordinate systems, he writes (p. 116, I modify slightly the notation) the following equation (it is intended that repeated indices sum):
$$
\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{Z_k}}\left(\left\{Z_k,Z_l\right\}_z|_{z(Z,t)}\right)\frac{\partial{H(z(Z,t))}}{\partial{Z_l}}+\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{Z_k}}\left(\frac{\partial{Z(z,t)}}{\partial{t}}\Big{|}_{z(Z,t)}\right)=0.
$$
He asserts that, since $H$ is arbitrary, the partial derivatives of each Poisson bracket $\left\{Z_k,Z_l\right\}_z\Big{|}_{z(Z,t)}$ with respect to the $Z$ coordinates must be $0$ and so we can at most write (the substitution $z=z\left(Z,t\right)$ can be omitted):
$$
\left\{Z_k,Z_l\right\}_z=c_{kl}\left(t\right)
$$
The derivation seems confirmed by an explicit calculation that the author does in the following chapter (p. 138 and 142), where he considers the phase space of dimension $2d=2$. For the case of a time-independent transformation, he takes the derivatives of the two equations for $\dot{Q}$ and $\dot{P}$ and adds them, according to the discussion above, obtaining (without explicitly showing the variable dependence):
$$
\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{Q}}\left(\left\{Q,P\right\}\right)\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{P}}-\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{P}}\left(\left\{Q,P\right\}\right)\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{Q}}=0
$$
In this case, the arbitrariness of $H$ forces us to conclude that both partial derivatives of $\left\{Q,P\right\}$ with respect to $Q$ and $P$ are $0$, thus verifying the assertion for this case (there's no time dependence here so we can conclude $\left\{Q,P\right\}=c=constant$).
Turning back to the general assertion for $2d>2$, how can mathematically such an approach lead to the desired conclusion if we have only one equation in the $d$ arbitrary $H$ derivatives which should multiply potentially $\frac{d^2\left(d-1\right)}{2}$ partial derivatives of the Poisson brackets? The $d$ terms would collect many partial derivatives, leaving us with no possibility to conclude that each of the four partial derivative, for every Poisson bracket, is zero.
